# Как отправлять альбом вместе с подписью в Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет, есть вопрос по **Telegram Bot Api**.
Суть вопроса вот в чем, если отправлять альбом в Telegram через приложение, можно указать текст сообщения
[image: Загрузка несколько изображений в 1 сообщение с текстом]

[image: Результат]

Но вот как это реализовать через бота? Метод [SendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup) не поддерживает **caption**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо все же использовать [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup), который позволяет задать массив обьектов [photo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto)/[video](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediavideo) в поле `media`.

У каждого из этих обьектов есть поле `caption`. Однако важно, чтобы `caption` был заполнен **только для первого элемента массива**, если в массиве будет больше одного элемента с `caption` то тогда телеграм не будет выводить текст под фото, а будет показывать его только при клике на фото.

Вот маленькая иллюстрация на js:

```js
{
  // ...
  media: photos.map((src, index) => ({
    type: 'photo',
    parse_mode: 'Markdown',
    media: src,
    caption: index ? undefined : apartment.message,
  })),
}
```